# Django printing status isn't working

Tags: django, django-admin, python-2.7

I have been trying a lot but could not make out why it happens,

```
class FortressUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    list_display(. . . , get_my_schema)

    def get_my_schema(self, obj):
        sql_query = "select prop_val from customer_property where customer_id = %d and property_value like '%%%%SCHEMA%%%%'" % obj.customer_id.customer_id    
        property_value = connection.cursor().execute(sql_query).fetch_one()        
        print sql_query        
        return 1
        # return "aditya"
    get_my_schema.short_description = 'Schema Instance'
```

- why the column values are always `(None)`
- why the `print 1` or `print 'aditya'` won't print anything to the console

Screen shot of the column admin site:
[image]

Comment: note that not all the values/strings are empty as I see from the database.

Comment: my bad!!!

It should be fetchone() and it works :-/...

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fetchone()` function instead of the one used above..